# Capture WebRTC stream

Tags: node.js, html5-video, blob, multipartform-data

I got this little proof of concept script that I copy/paste into Google Chrome console to capture live webcam video. I capture the chunks every 5 seconds, turn them into blobs, attach to a form data instance and post to a Node server. Then I clean up. It works, but eventually the browser crashes. RAM and CPU spikes heavily.

It seems the problematic areas are creating the Blobs and FormData variables.
How can I improve the script?

To test, go here:
https://www.earthcam.com/usa/arizona/sedona/redrock/?cam=sedona_hd

Copy/paste the script. Check the tab's RAM and CPU consumption.

```
let chunks = [];

const getOptions = function() {
  let options = { mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus' };

  if (!window.MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
    console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not supported`);
    options = { mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus' };

    if (!window.MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
      console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not supported`);
      options = { mimeType: 'video/webm' };

      if (!window.MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
        console.error(`${options.mimeType} is not supported`);
        options = { mimeType: '' };
      }
    }
  }

  return options;
};

const captureStream = async function(chunks) {
  let blob = new window.Blob(chunks, {
    type: 'video/webm',
  });

  let formData = new window.FormData();
  formData.append('upl', blob, 'myFile.webm');

  await window.fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData,
  });

  blob = null;
  formData = null;
  console.log(`Saved ${chunks.length}`);
  chunks = [];
};

const recordStream = function() {
  if (window.MediaRecorder === undefined) {
    return console.log('Not supported');
  }

  const video = document.querySelector('video');
  const stream = video.captureStream();
  const options = getOptions();
  const mediaRecorder = new window.MediaRecorder(stream, options);

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    if (e.data && e.data.size > 0) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    }
  };

  mediaRecorder.start(0);

  // Capture chunks every 5 sec
  setInterval(async function() {
    await captureStream(chunks);
  }, 5000);
};

recordStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

When I paste in the code above into the Console it displays this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
```

Adding a preceding { then returns this error:

```
VM97:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined at <anonymous>:3:11
```